# change image on link button with CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="buttons_position"><img src="images/order.png" height="49" width="214"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons_position {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.buttons_position a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ask_us_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

but on hover image is not changed. How to do this with CSS?

Comment: do you mean change `order.png` by `ask_us_hover.png`

Comment: that's cause <img> and background images are two very different things. try using a background image in both cases, rather than an image tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your background image is applied on hover to the a tag, and is covered by the img inside the a tag. Replace the img tag with text that you can hide (search for image replacement) and apply a different background to default and hover status of the a tag. it would be beneficial to have one single image (sprite) as a background and use background-position on hover.

image replacement: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

background-image sprites: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/

looking at the other answers, the correct way should be:

```
.buttons_position {
    background-image: url(images/order.png);
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.buttons_position:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ask_us_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

you might also need to set `display: block;` and width/height attributes to `.buttons_position`

Answer (score 3):

Remove image on IMG tag. Write like this:

```
.buttons_position {
    background-image: url(images/order.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.buttons_position:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ask_us_hover.png);        
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="buttons_position"></a>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/X9wCL/

Comment: do not leave the <a> tag empty, as it won't display anything in case of plain text browser / image failed to load.

Comment: i try this and i laso add display: block; that image is shown but hover not working

Answer (score 1):

try:
HTML:

```
<a href="" class="buttons_position"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons_position {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    background-image: url(images/order.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.buttons_position a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ask_us_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: do not leave the <a> tag empty, as it won't display anything in case of plain text browser / image failed to load

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
a.buttons_position:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ask_us_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 2149px;
    height: 49px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

your link is not inside an element with the class .button_position